# How do I limit a numeric setting?

Tags: ios, limit, appsettings

I have a simple setting in my app and want a numeric value limited to say 10,000. I have the entry in Root.plist and it is a PSTextFieldSpecifier. I can convert and limit the string entered but if the user enters 1234567890 that text remains in the settings and the user does not know I have limited it.

I convert using [defaults integerForKey] at the time I need to use that value in my program.

I've spent some time searching for the solution to this and as I haven't found the answer wonder if I am using the wrong approach.

Comment: your question needs a bit more detail: what kind of control is the user typing into? a text field *within* your app? or is it a Settings bundle?

Comment: Michael, sorry I should have made it clearer. It is simply a setting in the default settings bundle. The only reference I have to it is in Root.plist in the Settings.bundle. I can read the value out and I think I could replace it with the corrected value but I don't know how to get a delegate to run for each character entry as I don't have a UITextField available.

Comment: For the record I have been searching for an answer to this since the original question date and still not found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the number of digits the user can input in the text field by implementing the following text field delegate method : `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

This method is part of the textfield's delegate `UITextFieldDelegate`.
Conform your view controller to this protocol and implement the function as follows :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    int val = [string intVal];
    if (val > 10000)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

If you text field is not set to numeric only than validate the replacement string before converting to a number

Comment: Could you help me a bit more please giorashc (or anyone else). I understand the delegation and have seen how to link a text box in a normal view to a delegate function but as this is coming from settings I don't know how to set up the delegate.

Comment: in your view controller's init method add the following line : `self.textField.delegate = self;` (assuming textField is the UITextField controlled by your view controller) and make sure your controller conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`

Comment: Sorry giorashc the point is that as the default settings do not have a text field (as far as I know) I do not have the object textField to set the delegate for. I have only Root.plist which contains the information that the setting app creates a text field from. Maybe I just need to find how to get access to that?

Comment: I am confused a bit ... Where does the user input his number ? do you have a text field control for that ?

Comment: The user enters his number in settings. This is the Apple app that has 3 cogs in the icon. I've added setting information into Root.plist so that my settings appear for my app. No I do not have a text field control for that.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to provide instant feedback when the user is entering an invalid value in the settings app. However, you can reset the value once your app becomes active. ie this will address the problem where

> if the user enters 1234567890 that text remains in the settings and the user does not know I have limited it

eg:

```
NSInteger value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"my_key"];

if (value < 0 || value > 10000) {
    // invalid value

    value = 10000;

    // reset value shown in iOS settings app 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value] forKey:@"my_key"]];
}

return value;
```